I am using the Select from next ui but can figure out how to get the selected value out of it ans save it in a state
I am using the Select from the next ui in my nextjs project
i have succesfully implemented it and it is working fine but the problem is i cant get the selected value from it, i want to store the selected value inside a setState and i have tried using the onchange as the documentation suggested but i am getting the index instead of the string itself
Here's my code

   "use client";
   import React, { useState } from "react";
   import { Select, SelectItem } from "@nextui-org/select";

   const ServiceInfoContainer = () => {
   const [service, setService] = useState("");

   const categories = ["Beginner (0-1 year)", "Intermediate (2-3 years)", "Experienced (4-5        years)", "Expert (6+ years)"];

  const handleChange = (e)=> setService(e.target.value)

   <Select  onChange={handleChange} label="Select years of experience">
            {categories.map((categ, index) => (
              <SelectItem  key={index} value={categ}>
                {categ}
              </SelectItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
   }

when i console log the service i am getting 1 2 3 respective to the selected option like its giving me out the index instead of the string value
I want to get the selected value instead of the index i am currently getting

Your problem is the key, just use the intended value as the key in this example the category is the value so use it as the key.


"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Select, SelectSection, SelectItem } from "@nextui-org/select";
const ServiceInfoContainer: React.FC = () => {
  const [service, setService] = useState<string>("");

  const categories: string[] = [
    "Beginner (0-1 year)",
    "Intermediate (2-3 years)",
    "Experienced (4-5 years)",
    "Expert (6+ years)",
  ];

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setService(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      Service: {service}
      <Select onChange={handleChange} label="Select years of experience">
        {categories.map((categ) => (
          <SelectItem key={categ} value={categ}>
            {categ}
          </SelectItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </>
  );
};

export default ServiceInfoContainer;




